# Law of Cosines with imaginary arguments?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, hyperbolic-geometry, hyperbolic-functions

Does the law of cosines:

$c^2 = a^2 + b^2 - 2 a b \cos \theta$

work with imaginary angles? to get something like:

$c^2 = a^2 + b^2 - 2 a b \cosh \theta$

Alternatively, is there a hyperbolic equivalent for the law of cosines that has a similar form to the law of cosines? I know there's a hyperbolic law of cosines that involves cosh's and sinh's but I want something that looks like the regular law of cosines.

Comment: What's an "imaginary angle"?

Comment: I have a feeling (and you most likely chappers) he meant $\theta \to i\theta$

Comment: There is apparently something called the hyperbolic law of cosines. Perhaps you can read up on that, though it does look quite different.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_law_of_cosines

Comment: @Chappers yes, I mean $\theta$ goes to $i \theta$.

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong I've read that (obviously I googled this before posting here). Like I said in my post, I'm looking for an identity that looks like the regular law of cosines.

Comment: The problem is that the law of cosines isn't a trigonometric identity, it's a geometric identity. The quantities $a,b,c$ are defined geometrically. So the proper analog would have to be something with hyperbolic geometry, and the hyperbolic law appears to be just that.